# Check if module can be loaded into Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Is it possible to check if module can be loaded into Linux kernel, without actually trying this, i.e. before init_module (finit_module)?

It's trivial in kernel space, but the question is about userspace, which has no access to symbol versions, except for distribution-provided files like Modules.symvers, please don't suggest this.

My plan was to build any possible (at least vanilla) kernel and collect the CRC of symbols which are expected by module in question.
Then I realised the CPU usage prohibits this plan.

Perhaps there is some online service which has already done this and collected versions of any symbol in any (vanilla) kernel?

Comment: I'm curious now! Is there any reason why you wouldn't want to attempt loading the module and seeing what status/error was returned from `insmod`/`modprobe`?

Comment: Wouldn't *find* associated .ko in the /lib/modules/[running kernel name] subtree just suffice in telling about the compatibility a priori ?

Comment: On every such attempt kernel croaks frightening messages in dmesg.